# How is SQL Server's timestamp2 supposed to work in JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, datetime2, sqljdbc

I'm having some trouble trying to use timestamp2 instead of Timestamp in SQL Server 2008.  Apparently, rs.getTimestamp has very different behavior between timestamp and timestamp2.  However, I can't find any documentation stating that there should be a difference, or that I should be using something different.  I wonder whether I'm just doing something wrong.

Environment:

- Tried on both SQL Express 2008 (10.0) and SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.5).
- sqljdbc4.jar version 3.0, size of 537,303 bytes, CRC-32=a0aa1e25, MD5=402130141d5f2cee727f4371e2e8fd8a.
- Java 1.6

Here is a unit test demonstrating the problem.  The only "magic" is the "Db.getConnection()", which you can replace with appropriate code.  The test is the same for both datetime and datetime2, but the datetime2 test fails with a date that is 2 days prior.  I treat all times in the DB as GMT/UTC, and I haven't attempted to add timezone information into the database data for datetime2 data.

```
    private void testTimestamp(TimeZone gmtTz, Connection conn, String query,
                    Calendar expectedCal) throws SQLException
    {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next())
            {
                    // Note the expectedCal has a GMT timezone.
                    Date actualTs = rs.getTimestamp("dt", expectedCal);

                    // Just print out the time difference
                    long diff = actualTs.getTime() - expectedCal.getTimeInMillis();
                    System.out.println("Diff=" + diff);

                    // Do the test to make sure they are the same
                    // In practice, this succeeds for datetime and fails for datetime2
                    Assert.assertEquals(expectedCal.getTimeInMillis(), actualTs.getTime());
            }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDateTime() throws SQLException
    {
            Connection conn = Db.getConnection();
            TimeZone gmtTz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
            String query;

            Calendar expectedCal = Calendar.getInstance(gmtTz);
            expectedCal.clear();
            expectedCal.set(2011, 10, 02, 11, 17);

            query = "select CAST('2011-11-02 11:17:00' as datetime) as dt";
            testTimestamp(gmtTz, conn, query, expectedCal);

            query = "select CAST('2011-11-02 11:17:00.0000000' as datetime2) as dt";
            testTimestamp(gmtTz, conn, query, expectedCal); // results in an error
    }
```

Is my only option switching back to timestamp?

EDIT: For future Googlers, using sqljdbc4.jar version 3.0, the test fails on Linux, but passes on Windows.
I have not yet tried sqljdbc4.jar version 4.0 that comes with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: How different are the two values in the case it fails? Does that difference always remain constant? Also, can you reset the `expectedCal` after each test? Also, does it work if you don't pass a "GMT" calendar but a default `Calendar` instance?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas.  The datetime2 is always 2 days (48 hours) before the expected time.  Creating a new Calendar with the same values has the exact same difference.  Using the default calendar has the exact same difference.  So far, a problem any way I slice it.

Comment: OK, that narrows down the problem. Two more things if you can: 1) Does it still give incorrect value if you remove the additional precision i.e. the .000000 part 2) Is it possible for you to try it using another driver [JTDS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.2.5/)?

Comment: Removing the precision did not make a difference.  `JTDS` (which I had not heard of before, thanks for the reference) passes.  `sqljdbc4.jar` (version 2.0) works.  But `sqljdbc4.jar` (version 3.0) does **not** work.  Options now are probably a. use jtds; b. use sqljdbc4.jar version 2.0; c. convert db fields from datetime2 to datetime.  Or d. report the error to Microsoft and wait for them to fix their problem.

Comment: The comment discussion is getting a bit too long so I've moved my response to a new post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember not hearing good things about the official SQL Server driver and JTDS being preferred (though I can't seem to be finding that link). I would personally go with JTDS (with rigorous testing of course) or move back to the version which doesn't cause an issue. I haven't worked with SQL Server but from the looks of, it seems that `datetime2` is the preferred data type so I'd rather not revert back. Option (d) isn't really a good option IMO. :)

Comment: Thanks for your input throughout, Sanjay.  You really helped me figure out what the options are, which is awesome.  I'm not 100% sure which option I'll go with.  As you said, JTDS would require rigorous testing.  I will probably go back to sqljdbc4.jar version 2 or convert the fields back to datetime in the near term, and look closely at JTDS for the long term solution.

Comment: It gets more interesting.  Using sqljdbc4.jar version 3.0, the test fails on Linux (my production environment), ***but passes on Windows***.  I don't think this changes my options, but this information may be useful for anyone that finds this in the future.  So Microsoft is not completely crazy.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Sun JRE 1.7 with the Microsoft JDBC 3.0 driver see this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/01/20/hotfix-available-for-date-issue-when-using-jre-1-7.aspx.

If you feel you have discovered a bug in our driver you can report it via Microsoft Connect.
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer