# SQL and Java return different dates?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, date

I am using sqljdbc4.jar to connect SQL Server from my java application. I have a date field in my table. It works normally when I check from Sql Server Management Studio. But in java, every date is 2 day missing.

For example;

my date : 2012-01-10

date in java : 2012-01-08

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table1", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs2.getDate("dateCol").toString());
```

Why?

Comment: Could you try using SimpleDateFormat with `yyyy.MM.dd` format instead of .toString method?

Comment: Check your locale settins for both your database and java, are you sure that you are using the same time zone for both?

Comment: Same error [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982969/how-is-sql-servers-timestamp2-supposed-to-work-in-jdbc); proposes to use an other driver, JTDS.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the one that Joop Eggen linked to.

Comment: I just tried sqljdbc4.jar version 4, it fixed. Also there is no problem with version 2. Only bugged version is 3. [Download link for version 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried sqljdbc4.jar version 4, it fixed. Also there is no problem with version 2. Only bugged version is 3. [Download link for version 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774).

Thanks for answers.

Comment: If using Tomcat, don't forget to also check the `lib` directory for older versions of this jar.  It will override whatever is in your webapp.

Answer (score 0):

which version of SQL Server and which datatype are you using? There are 6 "date and time" [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) on SQl Server 2008:

```
date
datetimeoffset
datetime2
smalldatetime
datetime
time
```

maybe the one you are using is not supported in Java or by the drive you are using. Specially if you are using `Date` which is new in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

like @Eugenio Cuevas  said
please try formatting the date

Could you try using SimpleDateFormat with yyyy.MM.dd format instead of .toString method?

because looking at you date example ; may be its like a problem i faced before
the difference is 2 day because

1- 2012-01-10 and 2012-01-08 yyyy-mm-dd
2- 12-01-10 and 12-01-08       yy-mm-dd

that what caused my problem

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with somewhat similar problem couple of weeks. I had to save a java date in an oracle table which is typed sql date. You can not directly cast a java date to sql date. The following is what I did.

```
java.util.Date jDate = myObj.getDate();
java.sql.Date sDate = new java.sql.Date(jDate.getTime());
```